# Running total. CTE keeps running after the result has been fetched

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, cumulative-sum

Spent a few hours trying to debug the query and understand why it keeps scanning the whole table after the result has been fetched.

The query calculates the running total and should stop execution as soon as the limit is reached or exceeded. [TotalSize] >= @maxBlobSize

```
WITH TopRows AS ( 
                    SELECT 
                        [Id], 
                        [BinaryData], 
                        [CreatedAt], 
                        Sum([BinaryDataSize]) OVER (ORDER BY [CreatedAt]) as TotalSize 
                        FROM [dbo].[MessageLogs]) 
                    SELECT * 
                    FROM TopRows 
                    WHERE [TotalSize] < @maxBlobSize -- 10.000.000
                    ORDER BY [CreatedAt];
```

Comment: *should stop execution as soon as the limit is reached or exceeded*: This assumption is not correct. First, the CTE is executed (which actually scans the whole table), then the results are filtered.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Ok, guess there's no way to achieve that via SQL

Answer (score 2):

> The query calculates the running total and should stop execution as soon as the limit is reached or exceeded.

You don't understand how SQL works.  A SQL `SELECT` statement describes the result set.  It does not specify how the query is going to be run.

In your case, you have an operation that requires scanning the entire table:  the window function.  The SQL engine is going to calculate the cumulative sum over the entire table before the query finishes.

In our case, you are using `SUM()` and the engine doesn't know that `BinaryDataSize` is never negative.  Even if it did, I don't think any SQL engine would be smart enough to short circuit evaluation of the window function.